# I can't understand a syntax error issue in SQL / TimeScaleDB

Tags: postgresql, cast, timescaledb

This does NOT compile:

```
SELECT add_compression_policy(
    hypertable => 'exchange.candles',
    compress_after => INTERVAL ((SELECT now()::DATE::timestamp - (SELECT min(last_ts) FROM exchange.capture_tracker))),
    if_not_exists => TRUE);
```

The issue seems to be the `SELECT` following `INTERVAL`.

But this compiles:

```
WITH delay AS (SELECT now()::DATE::timestamp - (SELECT min(last_ts) FROM exchange.capture_tracker) myinterval)
SELECT add_compression_policy(
    hypertable => 'exchange.candles',
    compress_after => myinterval,
    if_not_exists => TRUE) FROM delay;
```

My colleague and I can't understand why.
Can anyone explain?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I think the `=> INTERVAL(...)` is the issue. Try `=> ((SELECT now()::DATE::timestamp - (SELECT min(last_ts) FROM exchange.capture_tracker)))::interval`

Comment: Or just `=> ((SELECT now()::DATE::timestamp - (SELECT min(last_ts) FROM exchange.capture_tracker)))`. Timestamp - timestamp should give interval as the output type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation

The *function* `interval()` does not do what you seem to think. You can use the type name like this to cast a value (typed or untyped):

```
test=> SELECT interval '5 days 20:32:32.06';
      interval      
--------------------
 5 days 20:32:32.06
```

But you cannot use it as *function* (followed by parentheses). That's only implemented for some basic types. See:

- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676871/939860)

There are two functions named "interval" registered in Postgres 14, one taking `time`, the other `interval` and `integer`. Not what you want:

```
test=> SELECT (proargtypes::regtype[])[:] FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'interval';
        proargtypes         
----------------------------
 {"time without time zone"}
 {interval,integer}
```

You seem to want a cast, but you don't need that to begin with, as the result of your convoluted expression is `interval` already.

#### Solution

Untangled:

```
SELECT add_compression_policy(hypertable     => 'exchange.candles'
                            , compress_after => (SELECT current_date - min(last_ts) FROM exchange.capture_tracker)
                            , if_not_exists  => TRUE);
```

`now()::DATE::timestamp` burns down to [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT). The latter is `date` instead of `timestamp`, but the result of the expression is the same. (Either depends on the `timezone` setting of your current session.)

Or, even simpler:

```
SELECT add_compression_policy(hypertable     => 'exchange.candles'
                            , compress_after => current_date - min(last_ts)
                            , if_not_exists  => TRUE)
FROM   exchange.capture_tracker;
```

Since the only reference to the table is `min(last_ts)`, this always returns a single row, even if the table is empty. And the result is the same as for the above.

Comment: Ok, I understand; so the parenthesis were making the interpreter think I was calling the function! That has us go in circle for a while. Thanks!